# HttpStatusCode not set in exceptions when using Google .Net APIs

Tags: google-api-dotnet-client

I'm having some issues when using the Google apis for .Net.
When calling a service and the call fails for some reason a GoogleApiException is thrown. The HttpStatusCode is always 0 in the exception. I can parse the status code from the Message but this is of course not a nice solution.

I'm using the latest binaries from NuGet (1.5.0.28972)

I'm also having problem with getting the ExponentialBackoff algorithm to work and i think it is related to this issue.

Below is som code to duplicate the behaviour.

```
    const string ServiceAccount = "000000000000@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
    const string KeyFile = @"C:\privatekey.p12";
    const string KeyPass = "notasecret";

    const string ApplicationName = "Test";
    const string User = "admin@some-domain.com";  // this is the user you wish to act for


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var certificate = new X509Certificate2(KeyFile, KeyPass,
                                           X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

    var provider = new AssertionFlowClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description, certificate)
    {
        ServiceAccountId = ServiceAccount,
        Scope = DirectoryService.Scopes.AdminDirectoryUser.GetStringValue(),
        ServiceAccountUser = User,
    };


    var authenticator = new OAuth2Authenticator<AssertionFlowClient>(provider, AssertionFlowClient.GetState);

    var initializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer
    {
        Authenticator = authenticator,
        DefaultExponentialBackOffPolicy = BaseClientService.ExponentialBackOffPolicy.UnsuccessfulResponse503
    };

    var service = new DirectoryService(initializer);

    // This will throw a GoogleApiException the the HttpStatusCode is 0 (Should be 409)
    var user = service.Users.Get("none-existing-user@some-domain.com").Execute();
}
```

Regards
/Tor

Comment: Can you attach the content of the GoogleApiException?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?